# Why does the same single-use regex behave differently in two platforms?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to validate an RFC (Mexican tax id) code in a form with JS and JQuery. I only require to validate whether the following Regex match returns `null`:

```js
function validateRFC(rfc) {
  const rgxFisica = "^(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})([0][13578]|[1][02])(([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])|[3][01])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|" +
    "(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})([0][13456789]|[1][012])(([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])|[3][0])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|" +
    "(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([02468][048]|[13579][26])[0][2]([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|" +
    "(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})[0][2]([0][1-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-8])([A-Z0-9]{3}))$";

  return rfc.match(rgxFisica) != null
}

const foo = validateRFC("XXXX901212UDX");
console.log(foo);
```

The pattern is basically `XXXXYYMMDDYYY` where `X` must be a letter, `YMD` are date values and `Y` can be any alphanumeric character.

I did a small unit test on codepen with my real id and it works. However, when testing it in my test environment it always returns null. [Here's a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFjRP.png) In case it matters, I'm rendering the entire page with Flask in Python 3.7, and the validation is inside `document.ready`

Is it possible that my Javascript is interpreting regular expressions differently?

**EDIT:**

It seems the embedded snippet also returns `true`. I'm using VS2019 16.3.5, Python 16.3.19252.1 in a Python 3.7 64-bit environment.

Comment: JS is executed in the browser, the location of the code doesn't matter.

Comment: can you state your environment?  sometimes between environments, say python, perl, or bash and ksh and so forth, there are multiple versions of regex that you might have to deal with.  Thanks.

Comment: The snippet works for me. Your screenshot doesn't show the value of `rfc` when it doesn't work, how are we supposed to know what's wrong?

Comment: What does Python have to do with it? The code is running in JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: Your python runs server-side, not client-side, where the validation is happening.  Are you also running this regex in python code?  If not, your python architecture isn't relevant to the issue, and is only serving to confuse us.

Comment: I'm a newcomer to the back-end side of things. I apologize for providing confusing information. Python renders the HTML/JS but the entire validation is performed by JS. I provided details about the environment because arcee requested it.

Comment: Which browser are you using when you get null?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases of javascript, like ECMAScript,  if the match fails, then the call `rfc.match(rgxFisica)` will return an array.  If the match passes, it will return a boolean `true`.

see example (https://jsfiddle.net/coq3Lugw/):

```
function validateRFC(rfc) {
  const rgxFisica = "^(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})([0][13578]|[1][02])(([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])|[3][01])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|" +
    "(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})([0][13456789]|[1][012])(([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])|[3][0])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|" +
    "(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([02468][048]|[13579][26])[0][2]([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|" +
    "(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})[0][2]([0][1-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-8])([A-Z0-9]{3}))$";
    console.log(rfc.match(rgxFisica))

    console.log("hello 0670 world".match(rgxFisica))

  return rfc.match(rgxFisica) != null
}

const foo = validateRFC("XXXX901212UDX");
//console.log(foo);
```

what I would do is set an if-then statement and return that way:

```
function validateRFC(rfc) {
  const rgxFisica = "^(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})([0][13578]|[1][02])(([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])|[3][01])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|" +
    "(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})([0][13456789]|[1][012])(([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])|[3][0])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|" +
    "(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([02468][048]|[13579][26])[0][2]([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|" +
    "(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})[0][2]([0][1-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-8])([A-Z0-9]{3}))$";

  if (rfc.match(rgxFisica)) == null{
      return True
  } else {
      return False
  }
}

const foo = validateRFC("XXXX901212UDX");
//console.log(foo);
```

An example of a TRUE regex match:

```
function validateRFC(rfc) {
  const rgxFisica = "^(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})([0][13578]|[1][02])(([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])|[3][01])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|" +
    "(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})([0][13456789]|[1][012])(([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])|[3][0])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|" +
    "(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([02468][048]|[13579][26])[0][2]([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|" +
    "(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})[0][2]([0][1-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-8])([A-Z0-9]{3}))$";

 console.log(rfc.match(rgxFisica));

  if (rfc.match(rgxFisica) == null){
      return true
  } else{
      return false
  }
}

const foo = validateRFC("hello 0670 world");
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: I tried this and changed the function so it always attempts to validate "XXXX901212UDX" directly, which works in the snippet. Still getting false. [Here's a screenshot.](https://i.imgur.com/wm3Ezxo.png).

Comment: are you expecting a true on this one, because it shows false to me when using regex101.com.  I added an example for a true version above.

Comment: I updated it from true to null.  see if that works.